# How to add a grouped count column (SQL/snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know how to get to the row counts, using

```
SELECT city,
 district,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY district)
FORM
 place
```

| City | District | row. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lon | STR | 1 |
| Lon | BUD | 2 |
| Lon | LBR | 3 |
| Lon | TES | 4 |
| NY | BRO | 1 |
| NY | WIL | 2 |
| Par | Cen | 1 |

but what I actually want is the totals, as follows

| City | District | row. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lon | STR | 4 |
| Lon | BUD | 4 |
| Lon | LBR | 4 |
| Lon | TES | 4 |
| NY | BRO | 2 |
| NY | WIL | 2 |
| Par | Cen | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

Using windowed [COUNT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count):

```
SELECT city, district, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY city)
FROM place
```

Comment: there are more cities with same name. but usually not in the same district

Comment: @nbk To properly count iin such case, there is need for additional column higher in hierarchy: `country/county - city - district`

Comment: no you need to add district to the partition

Comment: @nbk If you do as you proposed (PARTITION BY city, district) you will get `1` for each pair(city/district) for presented sample data which is not what OP's wants

Comment: you are right :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it using `group by` and `inner join`  :

```
SELECT p.*, s.COUNT_
FROM place p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT City, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_
  FROM place 
  GROUP BY City
) AS s ON s.City = p.City
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery for this

```
SELECT city,
 district,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) From place WHERE city = p.city) places
FROM
 place p
```